Why is the MediaWiki Vector skin not working?
I just freshly installed a MediaWiki with the following YouTube Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeHg8JAsQCU

and it worked out.
But sadly the skin is not loading and the whole website is displayed in a raw text. It looks like only the .php is loading. When I use the XAMPP Control Panel and go to the Apache error logs, the following text appeares:

script 'C:/Program Files/xampp/htdocs/wiki/skins/Vector/index.php' not found or unable to stat

My Vector folder does not contain an index.php file.
I don't know what the problem is and I scrolled through Google already but nothing helps. Does anybody has a clue? I appreciate your help! Thank you

index.php should be in the root folder. It seems that would be C:/Program Files/xampp/htdocs/wiki/index.php. Try to change your config to point to that index file maybe?

Oh good idea! Do you know where exactly I can find the config where I can change it? I went through all Apache config files but could not find anything,
